# What’s Ansible log rotation periodicity?

Tags: ansible, log-rotation

In `ansible.cfg`, I use the `log_path` variable to define where to save Ansible logs.
A log file is generated and filled automatically but log rotation seems ineffective.
I need information about Ansible logs rotation.

- When does log rotates - daily, according to file size, … ?
- Is it a file rotation or a file content rotation?

After defining log_path in ansible.cfg, I ran Ansible several times for several weeks. The logs are saved but there’s no rotation.

```
## ansible.cfg
log_path = /my/ansible/log.path
```

I would have two files:

- `/my/ansible/log.path` contains latest logs
- `/my/ansible/log.path.0` for example contains oldest logs

but I only have all logs saved in `/my/ansible/log.path`.

Comment: there is no log rotation, not sure why you assumed there is one.

Comment: Thank you. I read [this ansible.cfg example](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/examples/ansible.cfg) but I misunderstood the comment over log_path.

Comment: i agree, it does sound misleading the way it was worded. in any case, the official documentation is [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/) in case you want to have a deeper look.

Answer (score 2):

As written [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/examples/ansible.cfg#L109), there’s no log rotation with Ansible.

```
# logging is off by default unless this path is defined
# if so defined, consider logrotate
#log_path = /var/log/ansible.log
```